# How accurate is this LTspice model of common mode signals?

Tags: analog, ltspice, spice, common-mode

[image]

The 0.9MHz voltage source at the bottom is what I want to use to model common mode noise on the signal. Is this the correct way to think about this?

I am going to use this to do some analysis on that double balun and see if I can improve CMRR by adding a fully DA stage. In theory, if the 0.9MHz signal is attenuated then I have improved CMRR.

Comment: Are you asking specifically about the 0.9 MHz source?

Comment: No, I'm asking if the placement of the "noise source" is accurate.

Answer (score 4):

> The 0.9MHz voltage source at the bottom is what I want to use to model common mode noise on the signal. Is this the correct way to think about this?

No it's not quite right.

With this setup, the common mode input voltage would be

$$v_{cm}(t) = (50\ {\mathrm mV})\sin\left(2\pi(0.9\times10^6) t\right)+(0.5)(0.2)\sin\left(2\pi(6\times10^6)t\right)$$

That is, half of the signal from the 6 MHz source also contributes to the common mode voltage.

If you want to have one voltage source in your model that represents the common mode voltage, you can do it like this:

[image]

Of course you have to replace the `Vcm` and `Vd/2` with legitimate values that are meaningful to LTSpice. The main point is that you use two equal sources to produce the differential voltage, one adding and the other subtracting from the common mode source.

Comment: It shouldn’t matter whether the CM source is in between V2/V3 or on the negative side of V3 (or anywhere else).  

The AC component of the common mode will be the same regardless.

Comment: @asdf30, you should check your math on that. If \$v_{cm} = \frac{1}{2}(v_1+v_2)\$ then it absolutely does matter.

Comment: Yes and no.  V1 and V2 are the differential mode source and create differential mode currents that are not attenuated by a common mode filter. 

Any practical technique for measuring common mode should null this out.

Comment: @ThePhoton So in this case Vd/2 would just be half amplitude of my signal correct?

Comment: @MaxW, yes, the differential signal is Vd, but you have to model it with two separate supplies with value Vd/2 (and opposite polarity) so that the common mode voltage will just be Vcm.